# TypeScript support in WebStorm 2016.3 - tooltips like in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

Visual Studio Code has awesome TypeScript support, e.g. type inference that is shown in tooltips (when I hover over function that has no type defined). By default in WebStorm I only get Console/Errors inside tool window.

Are there any plugins / settings in WebStorm that will enrich TypeScript support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`View | Expression Type` (`Ctrl+Shift+P` in default keymap) allows to view the inferred type. You can also use `Ctrl+Q` (`View | Quick Documentation`) here.

Some other actions you may find useful:

- `View | Quick definition`: shows a tooltip with function definition
- `View | Parameter Infor`: when invoked within function call parentheses, shows information about function parameters

If you miss tooltips similar to VS Code, please vote for [WEB-19686](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19686)